# Ajax request inside loop, page reload after completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I m using Jquery ajax request inside loop, all goes well till the last request. but after last request, page automatically reloads.I m not being able to understand what is happening there.

Plz review and help.
I m using asp.net web form and web services for handling ajax request.

Jquery Code:

```
var mainData = GetFromExcel();

function StartSaving()
{
    for (i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) 
    {
        DoPost(i);
    }
}
function DoPost(i)
{
    var mainCode = MainData[i].MainCode;
    var noOfAllot = MainData[i].NoOfAllotment;
    var CompanyCode = MainData[i].CompanyCode;
    console.log(mainCode +' Company Code:'+ CompanyCode+':' + noOfAllot);
    $.ajax({
        url: "Allotment.asmx/DoAllotment",
        data: "{MainCode:'" + mainCode + "', sNoOfAllotment:'" + noOfAllot + "',CompanyCode:'" + CompanyCode + "'}", // the data in JSON format.  Note it is *not* a JSON object, is is a literal string in JSON format
        dataType: 'text',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "Post",
        async: false ,
        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        },
        error: function (res) {           
        }
    });
}
```

GetFromExcel is function that takes excelsheet and convert into json array. for that i have used xlsx.js

WebServices Code:

```
[WebMethod]
public String DoAllotment(string MainCode, string sNoOfAllotment, string CompanyCode)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    if(checkData())
        return "Error";
    else
        return "Success";
}
```

Comment: how is `StartSaving` executed? perhaps you need to prevent default form action - considering you're using `async: false` I would say that's exactly the problem ... don't you know that `synchronous XMLHttpRequest is deprecated on the main thread` in every modern browser? **don't do synchronous AJAX**

Comment: that is executed by javascript click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a common pitfall.

1. Modify your javascript method to return false, see below:

   ```
   function StartSaving() {
       for (i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {
           DoPost(i);
       }
       return false; //This is important for not allowing button click post back
   }
   ```
2. In The asp.Net button add OnclientClick as shown below:

   ```
   <asp:button ..... OnClientClick="return StartSaving();"></asp:button>
   ```

***Everything else is perfect in your code!!!!

Comment: thank you so much ... actually i am using html input button.... return false idea woked..